# How to use a pre trained image classification model which is type of h5 in Keras?

Tags: keras, deep-learning, classification, h5py

I trained an h5 model using Keras and i don't know how to use it on other programs for other images. And also this question is not duplicate or i couldn't find any solution for that. Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use models from keras library as below.

```
from keras open models
model = models.load_model("model.h5")
```